# Make parallel_test work in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parallel-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I get

> - bundle exec rake parallel:spec
>     8 processes for 56 specs, ~ 7 specs per process
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/gems/bundler-1.11.2/bin/bundle (LoadError)
>     from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in`'
>     /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load': cannot load such file --

when trying to run tests with the https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests project.

Anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: On which docker image does your pipeline depend? It seems that bundler is not installed on this image...

Comment: no no, it's all installed, it works without the parallel.. I'm using kinnrot/ctv-build